# `yum check-update` fails with an error in a CentOS virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos, yum

[image: screenshot]

The following error occurred when I enter the following CMD

```
sudo yum check-update
```

complete vm :

[image: complete vm]

Answer (score 0):

I have searched for this error and I have tried so many solutions but the problem was not solved **until I have disabled the IPv6 in that vm.**

you can disable it from the GUI through settings -> network -> wired -> click on the gear button -> under IPv6 > click disable

from the terminal:

> vi /etc/sysctl.conf

Add the following lines:

> net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
> net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1